# Override log format of OpenTelemetry agent logs

Tags: quarkus, agent, open-telemetry

I use the open telemetry java agent (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases) with my quarkus app.

The agent's log format is very different from what is required, e.g.

```
[otel.javaagent 2022-10-18 15:57:43:181 +0200] [OkHttp http://localhost:4317/...] ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4317
```

the quarkus custom log format is defined by

```
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p traceId=[%X{traceId}] spanId=[%X{spanId}] [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

How can I redefine or pass a specific log format that the agent is printing?

Answer (score -1):

Quarkus uses it's own OpenTelemetry instrumentation, no agent needed.
The log format `quarkus.log.console.format` is a Quarkus specific feature and is not picked up by the OpenTelemetry agent.
Instead of using the agent please configure this Quarkus extension:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will include the OpenTelemetry SDK, instrumentation and the default OTLP exporter.
For more details, please check: https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry

Comment: I must use the agent as quarkus-opentelemetry is atm not instrumenting quartz, aws sdk etc. This question is actually more directed to opentelemetry project members